# Overriding the fileName parameter while uploading a file in Postman

Tags: curl, postman, sql-injection

I would like to simulate a sql injection attack when uploading a file.
I have created a valid Postman POST Request (without SQL) for upload and it works fine:

[image]

Now I would like to change the **fileName** parameter which is sent along with the file and add there some SQL. In Curl I could do:

> curl ...
> --data-raw $ ------WebKitFormBoundaryau4kIDO0B4CDU3pf\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; **filename**="pom.xml' OR ' SELECT..., 'u'))'
> "\r\nContent-Type:
> application/*\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryau4kIDO0B4CDU3pf--\r\n'
> \

I do not see any place in POSTMAN where I can view or edit the additional parameters of the file. I am only able to pickup a file from the filesystem and name the form file param: "file".
How to change the fileName parameter in Postman?

Comment: It looks in your screenshot like Postman is taking the file name of the file you select. So can you just rename your test file to the appropriate name?